# Zoom page while printing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi
I am taking print as Landscape in javascript, as there was no standard code, so i changed it to like that i rotate my page div to 90 degree, which makes it landscape way and then perform window.print(), but the problem is,  i made it fool as basically it is PORTRAIT printing in landscape way, so the text is quite small, and fields also, i want that they should be zoomed, so is there anyway to zoom the page for printing.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a stylesheet [specifically for printing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-sheets)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css"/>
```

or [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule)

```
@media print {
  body { font-size: 10pt }
}
@media screen {
  body { font-size: 13px }
}
@media screen, print {
  body { line-height: 1.2 }
}
```

Comment: You have to create one yourself. The filename doesn't matter.

Comment: i have used the media queries, this is making a hope to success, just there is still a problem, that text fields are not becoming bigger, labels have been grown but text field and its font did not, i added the property of input{ font-size:13px;}  in @media print, what should i do?

Comment: in firefox the css is ok, but in safari, the page is not totally fit to the printed page, it is much smaller than the space available on the page, does zoom of css work in safari? as its not working on my side, how to zoom or fit the page, any idea?